# What are some javascript practices I should avoid for good SEO

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo

So I would like to know some things I should avoid doing in javascript for good SEO rankings. In my next site I will use jquery and javascript extensively but do not want to sacrifice SEO. So what do you think I should avoid doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Avoid placing content in Javascript (use html/css then **manipulate** with JS)
2. Use standard links in your html then override their functionality using events

Basically start by building your pages to work without javascript and then add javascript functionality as an additional layer.

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) is your friend.

Comment: This is correct. Make sure the site functions completely without Javascript. This will ensure that your HTML is SEO friendly.

Then, start intercepting clicks with jQuery to enhance the user experience (remember to return false).

The technique is called progressive enhancement. It makes for much easier debugging too.

http://clipperhouse.com/blog/post/A-few-more-reasons-to-use-Progressive-Enhancement.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article I found. Might be relevant for other engines as well:
http://www.softwaredeveloper.com/features/google-ajax-play-nice-061907/